# How pass props to external async components in typeScript and reactQuery?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have problem with pass props to external components in next.js
I have problem with line

```
  const { isLoading, data, error } = useQuery("products", getProducts(1));
```

getProducts(1)) -> How I should pass props to this component?

page:

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { getProducts } from "../components/task-1/getProducts-0";

export const ProductsPage = () => {
  const { isLoading, data, error } = useQuery("products", getProducts(1));

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (!data || error) {
    return <div>Error#!</div>;
  }

  return <>...</>;
};

export default ProductsPage;
```

component:

```
export const getProducts = async (id: number) => {
    const rest = await fetch(
        `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`
    );
    const data: ProductApi[] = await rest.json();
    return data;
};

interface ProductApi {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    image: string;
    rating: Rating;
}

interface Rating {
    rate: number;
    count: number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you perhaps further explain what the problem is?  It's not really clear what's going wrong and what you expect to happen

Edit:
I see the problem. You are actually invoking the `getProducts` function in your call to `useQuery`. You should pass a function to `useQuery`.
If you want to be able to parameterise the function, then you should create  what's called a closure, like so:

```
const getProducts = (id: number) => {
    return async () => {
        const rest = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`);
        const data: ProductApi[] = await rest.json();
        return data;
    }
}
```

What's happening here is, I'm return an async function that when called fetches the data from the API, and that is the function that I want to pass to `useQuery`

Comment: I want do use useQuery("products", getProducts(1)); but I see problem: No overload matches this call.

Comment: The problem is you are invoking the `getProducts` function inside of the call to `useQuery`, when `useQuery` expects the second argument to be a function.

Comment: How I should to do it? Can you show me correct code?

Comment: @robokonk look at my edit above

Comment: I still have this same problem. 
const getProducts: (id: number) => Promise<ProductApi[]>
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(queryKey: "products", options?: Omit<UseQueryOptions<unknown, unknown, unknown, "products">, "queryKey"> | undefined): UseQueryResult<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Promise<ProductApi[]>' has no properties in common with type 'Omit<UseQueryOptions<unknown, unknown, unknown, "products">, "queryKey">'....

Comment: The error that you wrote indicates that you didn't update your code to a function that returns a function. Did you remember to save the file or refresh the page?

Comment: @jo doe thanks, working well, what which wrong with me code?

Comment: when you invoking the function that you were passing into `useQuery`, and thus returning a Promise (Invoking an async function just returns a Promise), While `useQuery` requires you to pass in a function

Answer (score 1):

```
useQuery("products", getProducts(1))
```

this code will invoke the function `getProducts(1)` during render rather than passing a function to react-query - you're actually passing the result of the function to react-query.
Most example use inline functions for that matter:

```
useQuery("products", () => getProducts(1))
```

now react-query gets a function that it can invoke.

Additionally, the id should ideally be part of the queryKey, because it's a dependency to it:

```
const id = 1

useQuery(["products", id], () => getProducts(id))
```

if you do it that way, you can also potentially take advantage of the fact that react-query will inject the query key into the function you pass to it:

```
useQuery(["products", 1], ({ queryKey }) => getProducts(queryKey[1]))
```

It is best practice to *only* have your query function depend on things that are also inside the queryKey.